# bash text file transpose, add new column and make one big two-column again

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, tr

I have a large text file:

```
modularity_class;keys;columna1;columna2;columna3;
1;Antimalarial;Borneo;Cytotoxicity;Indonesia
0;Africa;malaria;morbidity;mortality
6;Anopheles albimanus;compression sprayer;house?spraying;;
12;;;;Tanzania;;
```

The final result should be:

```
Antimalarial;1
Borneo;1
Cytotoxicity;1
Indonesia;1
Africa;0
malaria;0
morbidity;0
mortality;0
Anopheles albimanus;6
compression sprayer;6
house?spraying;6
Tanzania;12
```

As you can see I need to:

- 1st: remove first row (should be trivial)
- transpose each row (one by one)
- add first value in original row to every element transposed as a second column
- skip every null/blank value between semicolon delimiters

I've read about `awk`, `sed`, `tr` and so on... but I cannot figure out how to get it in an efficient way.

**Note**: every row may have different length or elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `awk` should do the trick:

```
awk -F';' 'NR>1 {
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if($i!="")
            print $i FS $1
    }
}' file
```

One-liner:

```
awk -F';' 'NR>1 { for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) { if($i!="") print $i FS $1 } }' file
```

Comment: thank you, it did the trick. My knowledge using awk is so simple I couldn't guess this simple solution!!